# Как выводить только те записи к которых содержится номер телефона? PHP

Tags: php, парсер

Есть массив $result, в нем есть ячейки 'text' с текстом, вывожу их через foreach, $value['text'].  Необходим вывод только тех ячеек с текстом в которых есть номер телефона, единственное постоянное в номерах это комбинация 89 (пример 89777777777, 89888888888), подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать?

```
<?php

$result = file_get_contents ($url);

  $b = json_decode($result, true);
  foreach($b['response'] as $value) :

?>

   <textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="3"><?= strip_tags ($value['text']); ?></textarea> 

<?php
  endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: `array_column` и `preg_grep` в помощь. в чем конкретно проблема ваша?

Comment: Скрипт выводит все ячейки с текстом, нужен вывод только тех ячеек в которых содержится номер телефона а именно сочетание "89"

Comment: что-то вроде `$data = preg_grep("/89\d+{9}/", array_column($b['response'], 'text'));` и выводите `foreach($data as $v){ echo $v; }`

Comment: @teran наверное так правильнее `"/89\d{9}/"` :)

Comment: @Эдуард это да.

Comment: Не работает, выводит  поля <textarea> в каждом по одному такому символу   � 

Возможно я что-то не правильно делаю. Часть кода:

  $b = json_decode($result, true);

$data = preg_grep("/89\d{9}/", array_column($b['response'], 'text'));

foreach($data as $v) :



?>


   <textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="3"><?= strip_tags ($v['text']); ?></textarea>